Old PCMCIA flash card type 1 advice
I found an old synth (Alesis quadrasynth) from the early 90s which only loads sound patches, via PCMCIA cards type 1 (3mm).
Apparently it can read both AMD and Intel series 2, card protocols. Non ATA cards.
The thing with the AMD protocol cards is that they are very expensive. The Intel series 2 cards are way cheaper, but apparently they need a (PC or laptop) PCMCIA card slot with 12v supply, in order to write the files on the card.
Here’s a link to some relevant info
http://www.benweaver.info/alesis/
So my questions are:

What would be a good way to use a modern computer (either PCI-E or USB) for that job? An adapter or something appropriate? I repeat, non ATA flash card protocol, in case you missed the detail?

Do I need to find a particular old laptop just for the task?



This turned out to be a much tougher nut than I expected to crack. The good news is, there are some options!
1. Toshiba T4500/T4500C/T4600/T4600C - $100ish

Pros:

Likely compatible with all Linear Flash cards, including Intel Series 1/Series 2.
Relatively inexpensive, as the laptops are not considered desirable.
OS and software compatibility should be good.

Cons:

Few laptops available in validated working condition.
Incompatible with Windows XP and later; mediocre Windows 98 compatibility due to slow CPU.

While there are plenty of laptops out there with PCMCIA slots, the vast majority of them are only compatible with Type II/III PCMCIA cards. While Type II and Type III cards are compatible with Type I slots, Type I cards are not compatible with Type II or Type III slots.* This is rather unfortunate, since the window of time between PCMCIA being released and version 2.0 of the spec (which includes Type II cards) being released is extremely narrow: November 1990 to September 1991. Consequently, very few PCs shipped with Type I slots. Most devices that shipped with Type I slots, such as the Apple Newton, Neo Geo, and your synth, only did so because it was required to use SRAM and Linear Flash cards.
Furthermore, as you've discovered, 12V supply is not well supported. While it is part of the PCMCIA standard, 12V is only required to be available on the VPP pins. Consequently, many flash memory card designers either used the 3.3V/5V available on VCC and VPP, or generated their own 12V on the card since this was also allowed by the spec. Subsequently, many readers simply didn't bother to implement 12V support. Unfortunately, there's very little information online as to which readers did and did not implement 12V correctly. My guess is that earlier readers are more likely to have support, but I cannot validate this without trial and error.
As such, if you want to try and use an Intel Series 1/Series 2 card, I'm going to recommend you try an early Toshiba laptop. Toshiba was relatively popular brand at this time, and documentation for their laptops from the era—the Toshiba T series—is relatively available still.
Based on my research, the T4500/T4600 line is the one to go with, as it uses the original PCMCIA standard. The earlier T4400C does not have a PCMCIA slot, and while the T3300SL debuted an early version of PCMCIA to the world, it may not be fully spec-compatible. Similarly, the T4500/T4600's successor, T4700CS/T4700CT/T4800CT, comes with a PCMCIA 2.0 slot instead.
2. PowerBook 500 series

Pros:

Validated Type I compatibility.
Readily available in working condition.
Reasonable prices.

Cons:

No information on 12V support.
Little to no compatible software.

Remember that asterisk next to the statement that Type I cards can't be used in Type II/III slots? Well, that's not entirely true. Certain PowerBooks—namely those that only support the original 16-bit PC Bus standard, rather than the later 32-bit CardBus standard (introduced in 1995, in certain laptops from 1997 and later) can use Type I/II/III cards. This includes the PowerBook 500 series, the PowerBook 190/19cs, the PowerBook 5300 series, and the PowerBook 1400 series; it does not include G3 and G4 based PowerBooks. This was an intentional design decision, as detailed in this press release from 1994 and this (much longer) service document.
Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's not really any software to actually read from/write to Linear Flash on these devices. Based on one user's research—admittedly with a G3, rather than a PC Bus laptop—Mac OS 9.2.2 detects the card, but is unable to do anything further. This isn't exactly surprising, as Windows is similarly unable to do anything with these drives without third party software (I'll touch on this more later.)
As such, I don't think there's any reason to go with a PowerBook, unless you happen to have easy access to one and just want to try it out.
3. Any Windows 95/98/XP compatible PC with an 16-bit ISA slot, plus an SCM SwapBox - $100ish

Pros:

Validated Type I, Type II, and Type III compatibility.
Much greater hardware flexibility; not tied to old laptops.
Relatively cost-effective.
Probably good 12V support, since ISA must supply it.
Nice build quality.

Cons:

Potential driver issues.

Okay, perhaps dealing with old laptops isn't your thing. No problem! Meet the SCM Swapbox: a PCMCIA reader in a classic 3.5" floppy-like form factor, with an included ISA card. Since it's just an ISA card, we can put the card in any compatible motherboard. That includes everything from 386-based machines on Windows 95, up to 4th gen Intel Core on Windows XP (and even up to 12th gen if you really want to push it.) While finding newer motherboards with ISA slots can be a challenge, they do still exist thanks to the industrial sector, and there are tons and tons of older motherboards.
Unfortunately, the issue here is software support. In theory, the SwapBox should be a plug-and-play experience. From the manual:

Full-function PCMCIA support is included as a standard feature within Microsoft Windows '95. I f the SwapBox is already installed at the time of the Windows '95 installation, the software will detect the presence of the PCIC controller chip on the SwapBox ISA board and load the appropriate drivers. Any further configuration of the PCMCIA socket should be done through the Control Panel configuration options.

However, you may (or may not) run into some compatibility issues. This post on the Retrocomputing SE unfortunately didn't really go into detail on whether they were successful in their efforts, and this post notes some issues when trying to write data to one of their two flash cards (though this may have just been a bad card, since Linear Flash is only good to about 100,000 write cycles.)
Still, if you want a desktop setup or need more powerful hardware, this is probably the most sensible option.
4. OmniDrive USB2 - $535

Pros:

Plug-and-play over USB with robust support.
Works on modern OSs.

Cons:

Extremely expensive.

As you may have noticed, all of the solutions discussed thus far still require you to use an older version of Windows (XP at the newest), as they rely on the native Windows drivers to interface with the Linear Flash cards, which have minimal support in newer versions of Windows (more on this in a bit, I promise.) If that's a no-go, then the OmniDrive USB2 is your only option, as it uses third-party drivers that support modern Windows, macOS, and Linux. However, you'll be paying through the nose for the privilege, so unless you really need it, I'd consider another option.
5. Any old laptop with a PCMCIA slot, such as a Dell Latitude D620/D630/D820/D830 - $90ish
Pros:

Extremely cheap, since many, many laptops have some kind of PCMCIA slot.
Relatively modern hardware (as late as 2014, Dell was shipping a few ruggedized laptops with PCMCIA slots).

Cons:

No official support, may be unreliable.
Newer laptops unlikely to support 12V cards.

Okay, remember how at the start I said that Type I cards aren't compatible with Type II or Type III slots? Turns out that for many PCMCIA readers, they just... work anyways. This appears to include all ThinkPads, along with several validated models of Acer, Dell, and HP laptops. Perhaps this isn't entirely surprising given what we saw with the PowerBook and the SCM SwapBox, but it's intriguing nonetheless.
Because the cost of trying this setup is so minimal due to the proliferation of older laptops, assuming you can procure sufficient non-12V cards or an older laptop, this is probably the solution I'd go with. Yes, things may be flaky, unreliable, or unsupported—but unless you go with the OmniDrive, it's not necessarily going to be much better.
Final remarks
A word on software
As mentioned several times earlier in this post, working with Linear Flash cards isn't the "plug and play, mount in Explorer" experience that you may be used to with modern SD cards and other flash memory. Specialized software is required, with various options existing (including those mentioned in your original link.) In theory, Linux even includes a built-in driver, but it's supposedly been deeply broken for years.
The most popular piece of software is Elan Memory Card Explorer, as it provides a (relatively robust) read and write experience. Memory Card Explorer only supports Windows 95/98/ME/NT4/2000/XP due to OS/driver requirements, thus restricting our choice of hardware.
Additionally, Elan—the original developer—went bankrupt in 2012. Synchrotech acquired some portion of their assets, and will happily sell you a license for $323. However, given that Memory Card Explorer was originally distributed as freeware, I recommend downloading it from an alternative source. Just remember to always be careful when running random applications from the internet!
Why is this even necessary?
I'm rather surprised no one has made a Linear Flash emulator using modern flash technology. Modern FPGAs (and even microprocessors) are fast enough that they should absolutely be able to emulate vintage flash, as proven by the dime-a-dozen SD to IDE adapters out there. There's no technical reason you couldn't design and make your own, thought it'd definitely require some technical know-how.

Really impressed. So thorough.
Maybe for the first time ever in the internet someone replies in such a detail on this subject.
Thank you so much

Thanks! If you liked the answer, please vote it up, and if it worked for you, please accept it!

Haven’t got the privillige of voting yet. But my feedback was recorded. Could you please check my link below (like an answer to the question) to see if that adapter could work?

Could something like this work? Very cheap. But what’s its connectivity?
https://www.ebay.de/itm/312569411100?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110013%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIMRXI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D272609%2C272189%2C273631%2C273544%26meid%3D4b53929822b2460eb11ff0b7fc7e2a0e%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D310309364429%26itm%3D312569411100%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2332490%26algv%3DSimRXIVINativeV2WithSellersOwnItemsFilter&_trksid=p2332490.c101196.m2219&itmprp=cksum%3A3125694111004b53929822b2460eb11ff0b7fc7e2a0e%7Cenc%3AAQAJAAABEMd7r5mNjkO12hUFN8%252BUjou0r36TWdG4ts9ki5yV37PLn%252BNOULI4btYgHvyZLxyhY6cb20n6C4ymsgJYbSUOAjPUu4qAJ0Q2xTEmxx3a8Lg1GMBvPfrXrPn3rpLyTCXILJFPvFPpXrzfGmP1kUZR3pltPeyTBDhZFfBHz1TPPyyruPASKQDU4hiMQ%252BKpgL6sXWWCA6t5I7bNJ353fET60SuA773OWQ3ab3RCjvclbWMLGO797OrwgJb8OSKc6ol65x8ZK90UeHTfKtQl5tc4P91yJb1SAzpBBILAlXibtHUT7j2yfUpb7vHaE5awgOQR0hBhcwL5ye%252F37WOprI3MYnOpmlUcCtvzpCYx4qjfz%252Fzq%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2332490&epid=2217206785&itmmeta=01J7ZC3G68P1N3W9ZE8Z8ZYJ5Z

If you are not sure,  the its probably isnt an answer.  Plus you need to say something about it.   YOu are supposed to be recommending it!!

Not clear on what functionality this adds, nor how you would connect it to your intended computer.

Thanks once again. I really appreciate your knowledge and input.
If you think it’s unclear, to me it seems absolutelly weird. Have never seen or heard anything related to the description characteristics
